# Are there any buses from Liege or Vise to Maastricht?

Tags: buses, maastricht, liege

I am traveling to Maastricht and  I will be using Brussels airport.
The only issue is that I am arriving around 22h30 to Liege and the last train to Maastricht leaves around 22h40. It's very likely that I can't get this one.

I was wondering if there are any alternatives like a bus from Liege to Maastricht.
A bus from Vise can also work since the person giving me a lift can leave me there.

Any other information about buses connecting these two cities is welcome. The train between them only travels once an hour and it would be useful to know if there are alternatives.

Comment: An alternative might be to take the 21:11 train from Zaventem via Roosendaal and 's-Hertogenbosch to Maastricht, arriving at 01:04. But it takes almost 4 hours as opposed to 2:30 via Liege.

Comment: It's 53 euros by taxi - cheaper than a taxi from anywhere in London to anywhere else in London.

Comment: OV9292 (9292.nl) knows the trains between Vise and Maastricht, the last tonight leaving Vise at 22:45 (which is the same train you already found.) No bus information for this route on that site.

Comment: I don't understand. If you're using Brussels airport, why are you arriving at Liege? Shouldn't you be trying to solve the problem of getting from Brussels airport to Maastricht?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have a way of arriving to Liege from the airport. The problem is this last bit. I only mentioned the airport to explain my route.

Comment: @nsn But Liege doesn't seem to work so, instead of trying to make your via-Liege plan work, you should ask the question that you actually want help with. Ask for help with your actual problem, not the problem you made for yourself by bringing Liege into it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a bus between Liège and Maastricht, which passes Visé. It is [line 78](https://www.infotec.be/en-us/gettingabout/schedules/line.aspx?ligne=L78) of the Walloon bus company [TEC](https://www.infotec.be).

No, it doesn't solve your problem, because it goes less often than the train, less late than the train and takes ages in comparison to the train. I only would advise to take that bus if you need to get of at one of the intermediate stops not close to a station.

Additionally, the connection Liège-Maastricht is made by [Flixbus](http://www.flixbus.com). If I check on there website for a random day, I find one bus a day. But is leaves Liège at 22:45, which might give you a few additional minutes to make the connection in comparison to the train.